# How to obtain original coefficients after performing linear regression on normalized data?

Tags: machine-learning, python

I am reading data from a file using `pandas` which looks like this:

```
data.head()

   ldr1  ldr2  servo
0   971   956     -2
1   691   825   -105
2   841   963    -26
3   970   731     44
4   755   939    -69
```

I proceed to normalize this data to perform gradient descent:

```
my_data = (my_data - my_data.mean())/my_data.std()
my_data.head()

       ldr1      ldr2     servo
0  1.419949  1.289668  0.366482
1 -0.242834  0.591311 -1.580420
2  0.647943  1.326984 -0.087165
3  1.414011  0.090200  1.235972
4  0.137231  1.199041 -0.899949
```

I perform multivariate regression and end up with fitted parameters on the normalized data:

```
Thetas:  [[-3.86865143e-17,  8.47885685e-01, -5.39083511e-01]]
```

I would like to **plot the plane of best fit on the original data and not the normalized data** using the normalized thetas.

I used `scipy.optimize.curve_fit` to perform multivariate linear regression and come up with the optimal fitted parameters. I know that the original thetas should be close to the following:

```
[   0.26654135   -0.15218007 -107.79915373]
```

How can I get the 'original' thetas for the original data-set in order to plot, *without* using Scikit-Learn?

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Coefficients of the linear regression for unnormalized features

If parameters in the normalized space are denoted as $(\theta_0', \theta_1', \theta_2')$, parameters in the original space $(\theta_0, \theta_1, \theta_2)$ can be derived as follows
$$\begin{align*}
y' &= \theta_2'x_2'+\theta_1'x_1'+\theta_0'\\
\frac{y-\mu_Y}{\sigma_Y} &= \theta_2'\frac{x_2 - \mu_{X_2}}{\sigma_{X_2}} + \theta_1'\frac{x_1 - \mu_{X_1}}{\sigma_{X_1}} +\theta_0' \\
 y &= \overbrace{\left(\frac{\sigma_{Y}}{\sigma_{X_2}}\theta_2'\right)}^{\theta_2}x_2+ \overbrace{\left(\frac{\sigma_{Y}}{\sigma_{X_1}}\theta_1'\right)}^{\theta_1}x_1
 + \overbrace{\sigma_Y\left(-\theta_2'\frac{\mu_{X_2}}{\sigma_{X_2}}-\theta_1'\frac{\mu_{X_1}}{\sigma_{X_1}} + \theta_0'\right) + \mu_Y}^{\theta_0}
\end{align*}$$

#### Generalization to D features

$$\begin{align*}
\theta_d = \left\{\begin{matrix}
 \sigma_Y \left(\theta_0' - \sum_{i=1}^{D}\theta_i'\frac{\mu_{X_i}}{\sigma_{X_i}} \right) + \mu_Y& d=0\\ 
\frac{\sigma_{Y}}{\sigma_{X_d}}\theta_d' & d > 0
\end{matrix}\right.
\end{align*}$$

#### A trick

For visualization, we can plot the plane in original, un-normalized space without changing the parameters (`Thetas`). We only need to re-label (re-scale) the plot axes.

For example, a point $(x_1', x_2', y')$ in the normalized space corresponds to point $$(x_1, x_2, y)=(\sigma_{X_1}x_1'+\mu_{X_1}, \sigma_{X_2}x_2'+\mu_{X_2}, \sigma_{Y}y'+\mu_{Y})$$

in the original space. So you just need to rename the plot axes from $(x_1', x_2', y')$ to $(x_1, x_2, y)$.

Note that $y'=\theta_2'x_2'+\theta_1'x_1'+\theta_0'$ is still calculated using normalized features.

Comment: Thank you, this helps! I will try your suggestions and get back to you. Confirming that I understood correctly, in reference to your last equation, should I multiply the standard deviation of both normalized and original parameters and add to it the variance of the original parameter?

Comment: @Rrz0 There is no variance or std for *parameters* $\theta$. $\sigma$ and $\mu$ are calculated from *original* data.

Comment: Right, thanks for confirming. I am still not able to visualize the proper plane. I managed to convert the normalized data into the original space, however the plane appears incorrectly. I edited the question.

Comment: @Rrz0 I added a note. I suggest you try the first approach, probably it is more straightforward

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I feel I am still missing something fundamental. I am doing as you say, the normalized points fed into `z = theta.flat[0] * X + theta.flat[1] * Y + theta.flat[2]` are not being scaled back. I am also re-scaling the axis as I show in the edited question. I am also renaming the axis such that I plot data in original space.

Comment: @Rrz0 you should plot (x_scaled, y_scaled, z_scaled), also check out the manual on `plot_surface` maybe that is the problem, see whether you can plot an arbitrary surface. I suggest also implementing the first approach to better find the problem.

Comment: Thank you, last question: Working out the first approach I get a (175,1) vector as an output. Shouldn't this be just a single value? For example, to obtain the otiginal `theta2` I am doing: `((std_original[2]/std_original[1])*params[2]) * x2`

Comment: @Rrz0 remove $x_2$, it should not be included